# How to install openjdk on a machine without internet connection? Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, openjdk

First excuse me as I am a newbie...

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 without an internet connection. I have the ISO file of the installation already mounted. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the java setup files should be in the repository.

My questions are:

1. What is the name of the JDK package on the CD?
2. What is the command to run the install?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html

Click on that link I hope it helps you out :).

Answer (score 1):

Go to a Internet Cafe. Open the website http://www.ubuntuupdates.org.

Here in the package search type and find the following packages for Precise security main releases.

```
openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-headless libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java jarwrapper update-java openjdk-7-source openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-demo  openjdk-6-source openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-6-demo  openjdk-7-doc openjdk-6-doc
```

Download the .deb file in the site and save into a pen drive and bring them home.

Then install those packages with the following command :

```
sudo dpkg -i [PACKAGE NAME}
```

Comment: there isnt any openjava or any kind of java DEB installation file on the installation cd?

Comment: If present, these should be installed at the initial installation.